# Rails Activerecord - is there a callback before drop_table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

Is there a callback, before migration rollback or before table destroy?

But, if no such callback, how to emulate it?

Comment: There is no such callback.

Comment: You will have to patch Rails to have such callback in place. Not sure if the effort worth.

Answer (score 1):

There is not.
See the [list of available callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).